# What does undefined extension class 'Smarty_Internal_Method_Assign_By_Ref' Mean?

Tags: error, installation, smarty

The new installation of CIVI works. LAMP server, shared hosting, PHP 7.2, Joomla! 3.9, etc. 
When I click to go to configuration checklist, I get the error:
undefined extension class 'Smarty_Internal_Method_Assign_By_Ref'

Same when trying to run the component.

Can't find an answer to this on Stack Exchange or general search.

Appreciate any suggestions.

John

Comment: After update smarty for PHP 7.4.9 above error also start with me. Is there is any solution ?